# Check username using AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am having problems with validation using AJAX. I want to check if a given username exists. Here is my relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#uname").blur(function(){
        $.post("usernameCheck.php",{user_name:$(this).val()},function(data)
        {
            if(data=="no"){
                $("#checkUsername").html("This username already exists");
            }
            else{
                $("#checkUsername").html("Username is available!");
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

I can't figure out why the message cannot show. I think there might be something wrong within the AJAX validation.

Comment: Did you checked with firebug and verified what are you sending and what are you receiving in the AJAX call?

Comment: I already figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your Javascript is OK, except for the update part. `$(this)` updates what? You need to update a particular tag, like `$('#unameAvail')`.

Comment: What I want is when the username field loses focus, the message inside html() will display beside the filed to show whether this is an available username for the new user. I am not sure how to implement that, can you help me out with the code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, I understand that's what you want. What you need is to put a table column next to the text box, `<td id='unameOK'></td>`, and then do `$('#unameOK').html ('Username Available');`.

Comment: You can check out this tutorial, I basically followed it. I am sure I must have missed something...http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/check-username-available-ajax-php-jquery.html

Comment: Ahh... How stupid I am! I was missing closing bracket and semi-colon at the end. Now it is all working! Thank you very much!